# Derivative of Neural Network in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

I have implemented and trained a neural network in Pytorch, however, I am interested in the derivative of the neural network parameters with respect to the input.
I have extensively searched for any procedure to that would allow evaluating the derivative of weights with respect to a given input, but I did not find anything.
I know that I can compute the gradients of a function in the following way.

```
external_grad = torch.tensor([1., 1.])
Q.backward(gradient=external_grad)
```

But How would I do that with a trained neural network instead of a function Q?

Thanks in advance.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8

# In[1]:


import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy import linalg as la
import numpy.random as npr
from tabulate import tabulate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
import os
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
#from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable


# In[2]:


import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm
from numpy import linalg as la
import numpy.random as npr
from tabulate import tabulate
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import random
import os
import torch
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
#from torchvision import datasets, transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from torch import optim


# In[3]:


nSimul = 32768
T1 = 1.0
T2 = 2.0
K = 110.0

spot = 100.0
vol = 0.2
vol0 = 0.5 # vol is increased over the 1st period so we have more points in the wings


# simulate all Gaussian returns (N1, N2) first
# returns: matrix of shape [nSimul, TimeSteps=2]
returns = np.random.normal(size=[nSimul,2])

# generate paths, step by step, and not path by path as customary
# this is to avoid slow Python loops, using NumPy's optimized vector functions instead

# generate the vector of all scenarios for S1, of shape [nSimul]
S1 = spot * np.exp(-0.5*vol0*vol0*T1 + vol0*np.sqrt(T1)*returns[:,0])

# generate the vector of all scenarios for S2, of shape [nSimul]
S2 = S1 * np.exp(-0.5*vol*vol*(T2-T1) + vol*np.sqrt(T2-T1)*returns[:,1])

# training set, X and Y are both vectors of shape [nSimul]
X = S1
Y = np.maximum(0, S2 - K)
xAxis = np.linspace(20, 200, 100)

xAxis=xAxis.reshape(-1,1)


# In[4]:


#Normalization of the simulated data:

meanX = np.mean(X)
stdX = np.std(X)
meanY = np.mean(Y)
stdY = np.std(Y)

normX = (X - meanX) / stdX
normY = (Y - meanY) / stdY


normX=normX.reshape(-1,1)

normY=normY.reshape(-1,1)


# In[5]:


class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,inputsize,outputsize):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        #self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(inputsize,3),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Linear(3, 5),
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Linear(5,3), 
            nn.ELU(),
            nn.Linear(3,outputsize),
        )
        w = torch.empty(0,1)
        nn.init.normal_(w)
    
    def forward(self, x):
        #x = self.flatten(x)
        logits = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return logits


# In[6]:


inputDim = 1       # takes variable 'x' 
outputDim = 1       # takes variable 'y'
learningRate = 0.05
epochs = 10000
#weight=torch.empty(3)
model = NeuralNetwork(inputDim, outputDim)
##### For GPU #######
if torch.cuda.is_available():
    model.cuda()
    


# In[7]:


#criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss() 
#optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=learningRate)


# In[ ]:


def ridge_loss(outputs,labels):
    torch.mean((outputs-labels)**2)
    
    
    
    
    
    
    


# In[ ]:





# In[9]:


#Adam optmization
criterion = torch.nn.MSELoss() 
#optimizer = optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=0.01, momentum=0.9)
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.05)


# In[10]:


for epoch in range(epochs):
    # Converting inputs and labels to Variable
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(normX).cuda().float())
        labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(normY).cuda().float())
    else:
        inputs = Variable(torch.from_numpy(normX).float())
        labels = Variable(torch.from_numpy(normY).float())

    # Clear gradient buffers because we don't want any gradient from previous epoch to carry forward, dont want to cummulate gradients
    optimizer.zero_grad()

    # get output from the model, given the inputs
    outputs = model(inputs)

    # get loss for the predicted output
    loss = criterion(outputs, labels)
    print(loss)
    # get gradients w.r.t to parameters
    loss.backward()

    # update parameters
    optimizer.step()

    print('epoch {}, loss {}'.format(epoch, loss.item()))


# In[11]:


def predict(xs):
    # first, normalize
    nxs = (xs - meanX) / stdX
    # forward feed through ANN
    # we don't need gradients in the testing phase
    with torch.no_grad():
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            nys = model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(nxs.rehape(-1,1)).cuda().float())).cpu().data.numpy()
        else:
            nys = model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(nxs.reshape(-1,1))).float()).data.numpy()
    
    # de-normalize output
    ys = meanY + stdY * nys
    # we get a matrix of shape [size of xs][1], which we reshape as vector [size of xs]
    return np.reshape(ys, [-1])


# In[13]:


def BlackScholes(S0,r,sigma,T,K):
    d1 =  1 / (sigma * np.sqrt(T)) * (np.log(S0/K) + (r+sigma**2/2)*T)
    d2 = d1 - sigma * np.sqrt(T)
    return norm.cdf(d1) * S0 - norm.cdf(d2) * K * np.exp(-r*T)

def BlackScholesCallDelta(S0,r,sigma,T,K):
    d1 =  1 / (sigma * np.sqrt(T)) * (np.log(S0/K) + (r+sigma**2/2)*T)
    return norm.cdf(d1)

BlackScholes_vec=np.vectorize(BlackScholes)

BlackScholesCallDelta_vec=np.vectorize(BlackScholesCallDelta)


# In[14]:


BS_price=BS_prices=BlackScholes_vec(S0=xAxis,r=0,sigma=0.2,T=1.0,K=110.0)
predicted=predict(xAxis)

S1=1
#line_learn = plt.plot(Sval,y,label="Deep Neural Net")
line_learn = plt.plot(xAxis,predicted,label="Neural Regression")
line_BS = plt.plot(xAxis,BS_price, label="Black-Scholes")

plt.xlabel("Spot Price")
plt.ylabel("Option Price")
#plt.title(r'Time: %1.1f' % time, loc='left', fontsize=11)
plt.title(r'Strike: %1.2f' % K, loc='right', fontsize=11)
plt.title(r'Initial price: %1.2f' % S1, loc='center', fontsize=11)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
#plt.savefig("deephedge.png", dpi=150)
plt.savefig("deephedge.pdf")


# In[15]:


Prices_rg_mc_diff=[]

for i in range(len(xAxis)-1):
    delta=(predicted[i+1]-predicted[i])/(xAxis[i+1]-xAxis[i])
    Prices_rg_mc_diff.append(delta) 


# In[16]:


BS_delta=BlackScholesCallDelta(S0=xAxis,r=0,sigma=0.2,T=1.0,K=110.0)
predicted=predict(xAxis)

S1=1
#line_learn = plt.plot(Sval,y,label="Deep Neural Net")
line_learn = plt.plot(xAxis[1:],Prices_rg_mc_diff,label="Neural Regression")
line_BS = plt.plot(xAxis[1:],BS_delta[1:], label="Black-Scholes")

plt.xlabel("Spot Price")
plt.ylabel("Option Price")
#plt.title(r'Time: %1.1f' % time, loc='left', fontsize=11)
plt.title(r'Strike: %1.2f' % K, loc='right', fontsize=11)
plt.title(r'Initial price: %1.2f' % S1, loc='center', fontsize=11)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
#plt.savefig("deephedge.png", dpi=150)
plt.savefig("deephedge.pdf")


# In[17]:


model.backward(retain_graph=True)


# In[ ]:


print(NeuralNetwork.weight.grad)


# In[ ]:


def predict(xs):
    # first, normalize
    nxs = (xs - meanX) / stdX
    # forward feed through ANN
    # we don't need gradients in the testing phase
    with torch.no_grad():
        if torch.cuda.is_available():
            nys = model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(nxs.rehape(-1,1)).cuda().float())).cpu().data.numpy()
        else:
            nys = model(Variable(torch.from_numpy(nxs.reshape(-1,1))).float()).data.numpy()
    
    # de-normalize output
    ys = meanY + stdY * nys
    # we get a matrix of shape [size of xs][1], which we reshape as vector [size of xs]
    return np.reshape(ys, [-1])


# In[21]:


c3=torch.from_numpy((predicted.reshape(-1,1)), requires_grad=True) 
c4=torch.from_numpy(xAxis, requires_grad=True) 
#c5=torch.Tensor(c3) 
#c6=torch.Tensor(c4)  
loss = criterion(c3,c4) # calculating loss   

loss.backward()


# In[28]:


torch.tensor(predicted.reshape(-1,1), requires_grad=True)
torch.tensor(xAxis, requires_grad=True)

criterion(torch.tensor(predicted.reshape(-1,1), requires_grad=True),torch.tensor(xAxis, requires_grad=True))


loss.backward()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to explicitly use `requires_grad = True` when create a tensor. And to calculate gradient you first need to apply some operation on the tensor.

**Here is an example:**

```
import torch

x = torch.rand(2, 2, requires_grad=True)
y = x + 2
z = y * y * 3
out = z.mean()

out.backward()

print(x.grad)
```

Output:

```
tensor([[3.3720, 3.4302],
        [3.4030, 3.3605]])
```

In this way you are using `torch.autograd` to calculate the gradient for tensor `x`. See [autograd](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/autograd.html) for more.

And for neural network you can simply use the network and backward it afterward.

**A neural network Example:**

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as f

x = torch.rand(2, 2)

# define a neural network
network = nn.Sequential(
nn.Linear(2,100),
nn.Linear(100,2)
)

pred = network(x)

loss = f.mae_loss(pred, x) # calculating loss 

loss.backward()

# Update weights with gradients
network[0].weight = 0.1 * network[0].weight.grad
network[1].weight = 0.1 * network[1].weight.grad
```

Note: I didn't put any activation function in network for the sack of simplicity.

**Example of `backward()` using `torch.nn.MSELoss()`:**

```
import torch
from torch.nn import MSELoss

criterion = MSELoss()

a = torch.tensor([1.,2.], requires_grad=True)
b = a**2

loss = criterion(b, a)

loss.backward()

print(a.grad)
```

Output:

```
tensor([0., 6.])
```

Comment: My problem is that I want to apply it to a trained neural network, and not to a basic function. How would you do that?

Comment: I can solve for a function like f(x)=x^2 but I do not know how to apply it to a trained nural netwrok.

Comment: Is your network implemented with pytorch ? and are you wrapping your layer with Sequential ?

Comment: @MagnusMoller Here I edited and added an simple neural network example.

Comment: I have a problem since "AttributeError: module 'torch.nn.functional' has no attribute 'criterion'". "criterion" is my loss function.

Comment: `criterion` is used as a function variable it is not included in the pytorch library. Usually we use `criterion= nn.CrossEntropyLoss()` for classification problem and we calculate loss by calling like this `loss = criterion(y_hat, y)`. For my example you could use `criterion = nn.MSELoss()` and then call  `loss = criterion(y_hat, y)`.

Comment: ```loss = criterion(torch.from_numpy(predicted.reshape(-1,1)), torch.from_numpy(xAxis)) # calculating loss 

loss.backward()``` I did this. Then I ran and obtained now this error: runtime error: element 0 of tensors does not require grad and does not have a grad_fn

Comment: The tensors are not zero. I have printed them.

Comment: You can't use NumPy arrays like this `torch.from_numpy(predicted.reshape(-1,1)`. First you need to initialize all the values in `torch.Tensor`.

Comment: What do you mean by initializing the values?

Comment: Do this `torch.from_numpy(predicted.reshape(-1,1)` at the beginning. Because when you initialize a tensor it also comes with a gradient variable. Which it's uses one the way to calculating stuffs and then uses the grad to backpropagate. But you used them after passing them in the network.

Comment: ```c3=torch.from_numpy(predicted.reshape(-1,1))
c4=torch.from_numpy(xAxis)
loss = criterion(c3,c4) # calculating loss 

loss.backward()``` It does not work like this. How would I write it?

Comment: I tried to do also this ```c3=torch.from_numpy(predicted.reshape(-1,1))
c4=torch.from_numpy(xAxis)
c5=torch.Tensor(c3)
c6=torch.Tensor(c4)

loss = criterion(c5,c6) # calculating loss 

loss.backward()```  But I get the same error message.

Comment: `torch.tensor(predicted.reshape(-1,1), requires_grad=True)`

Comment: After running ```criterion(torch.tensor(predicted.reshape(-1,1), requires_grad=True),torch.tensor(xAxis, requires_grad=True))


loss.backward()``` I get the following run time error:RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

Comment: Can you show me the code?

Comment: I am using the code I have on grey in the previous comment.

Comment: Or do you want the entire code?

Comment: Put it on [colab](https://colab.research.google.com/) and share the notebook.

Comment: I have pasted it on your answer, once I do not know how to work with colab

Comment: I have pasted it on my question as well.

Comment: Check the last edit.

Comment: I have altered it into the following: ```criterion(torch.tensor(predict(xAxis).reshape(-1,1), requires_grad=True),torch.tensor(xAxis))


loss.backward()```

Comment: But, it does not work.

Comment: Did you find a way to make it work?

Comment: I do not see how your edit differs. How does it correct my implementation?

Comment: There might be something to do with the shape or value of `predicted.reshape(-1,1)` and `xAxis`.

Comment: I have tried different shapes. The same error occurs.

Comment: Please do them separately from your main code. Use my following code from the last block and edit from there.